# How can Mail.app in Mavericks show a messages plain text alternative?

Tags: mail.app, email, macos

A few days ago I wanted to verify that a simple multipart html/text mail I was about to send would render correctly in different mail clients. Does anyone know how to let Mail.app under Mavericks show the plain text alternative for an email? It used to be an option in the menus in previous releases, but now it seems to be gone.

Comment: View raw is not a solution for examining multi-part/alternative emails. There is nothing faulty about using base64 for the Content-Transfer-Encoding, and in these cases there will be nothing to look at in raw except for a long string of characters. As a developer, like Asmus, it's quite annoying that mail.app no longer supports an 'alternative' renderer. Instead, I've had to switch to gmail. In gmail, I can use the "Message text garbled?" Menu option to see the plain-text alternative. Apple, heads up. You don't want people to have to switch to gmail.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Apparently **there is no way** to do this with mavericks' Mail.app.

The option in the menu is gone and [setting it by hard](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030711201917175) in the plist file doesn't seem to work anymore either, according to [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23526803#23526803) and [this post](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23485734#23485734).

Unfortunately you have to **switch to a different mail client** if you want to have proper multi-format support.

Or, for testing purposes, you could just *send you the email in plain text* and see how it looks and then *verify that both parts are present* by looking at the raw mail text (which Mail.app still lets you do).

Comment: That is not correct. Try using Raw in View message.

Comment: @Buscar Yes, like I mentioned in the last paragraph of my message.

Comment: Raw is in general cannot be used for seeing Rendering.  Anything other than ascii (that means all accents, all smart punctuation, all emoji) will be encoded as base64 or quoted printable.

Comment: @TomGewecke Is that not true for the plain text version in general? I thought it was. Not that I think the RAW version is any usefull to look at when you're searching for the plain text version of an HTML mail.

Comment: No.  The plain text version should always convert any content transfer encoding to the proper characters for display, so you see the accents, smart quotes, and emoji. Plain text is not the same as ascii -- it just means that no styling (fontface, fontsize, color, etc) info is provided inside the message.  That is provided instead by the default settings of the reader.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Thanks for explaining. I think for the purpose of the question, RAW might be sufficient, but for everyday use, it doesn't make sense. Even less so with what you said.

Comment: Yes, if you send yourself an email with the single word "resumé" and look at its raw source, you can see that it's not useful for knowing how the reader will see it.

Comment: Apparently you're right, unfortunately. Seems this is not going to be fixed (ever..) so I'll accept this answer.